# What is the terminal velocity of SpaceX Starship?

Tags: reentry, physics, spacex-starship, aerodynamics, velocity

What is the terminal velocity of starship on earth and mars during descent?

Has SpaceX revealed or hinted the values of projected surface area and drag coefficient of the vehicle?

Comment: That'll depend on the ballistic coefficient, wchich will depend on the design, control surface position and mass.

Comment: @JCRM And altitude.

Comment: and weather @RussellBorogove

Comment: I'll bet $1.602  \times 10^{-19}$ bitcoin that it's 85$\pm$10% of the terminal velocity of an equivalent right elliptical cylinder of my choosing after the correct answer is posted.

Comment: @uhoh I thought about doing the math, but I'd have to guesstimate mass and look up published dimensions and bleaaaahhhhhhh

Comment: @RussellBorogove ya that's why I stipulated that the right answer had to be posted *first!*

Answer (score 9):

I have been looking for the same thing.  The only mention I found was on a blog post (https://www.neowin.net/forum/topic/1402753-spacex-starship-sn8-15km-test-flight/) which stated 66-68 m/s for SN8.  If true, that would imply ± 320 m/s on Mars.

Despite Mars' lower value for g (3.72), the much lower atmospheric density of 0.02 versus 1.2 kg/m3 results in a much higher Vt.  This of course assumes that everything else remains constant (mass, area, Cd).